# Home-automation x10 with a Linux based NAS (synology)

Tags: php, linux, nas, x10, home-automation

I have automated my home with the x10 protocol and use the cm15pro interface on my computer to program the switches.

Now I want to connect the cm15pro interface to my synology NAS and run commands with PHP on the NAS to the interface

Are there programs for running the cm15pro under Linux on a NAS, and is there a command-line tool for Linux to send the x10 signals from a NAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some linux drivers
http://misterhouse.wikispaces.com/X10-CM15A

The cm15a drivers works for cm15pro too

Comment: Thx :) it almost compile, first updating kernel

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [heyu](http://www.heyu.org) for a long time for my CM11 but unfortunately, they don't support the CM15. In fact, I didn't buy the CM15 at the time because it wasn't support in Linux in any way.

Seeing this question I went to see if things had changed in the meantime and found [mochad](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mochad/index.php?title=Main_Page). They don't mention the CM15Pro but they do support the CM15A so I guess it's worth giving it a try.